# curved div with transparent top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create transparent div full width and height around 500px using borders but i have trouble with creating this kind of curved shape.
It should look like on the example image, the yellow shape.
[image]

```css
.transparent_bg {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 485px;  
    background: transparent;
    border:solid 5px #000;
    border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-radius: 50%/200px 200px 0 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.transparent_bg:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 485px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent_bg"></div>
```

I have included a link to my work until this moment but without success.

Comment: Try SVG instead

Comment: If it's an oval, you can do it with the `border-radius: 1 2 3 4 / 5 6 7 8;` notation. Otherwise yep, SVG. Also, where's your content if there's any?

Comment: there is no content for now. Main idea is to create this oval shape and the picture above is going to be a slider with few images and each image should change behind the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use clip path in both ways (on the top element or the bottom one) and simply make top and bottom to overlay like this :

```css
.first,
.second {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.first .top {
  clip-path: circle(72.9% at 50% 27%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  position: relative;
}

.first .bottom {
  margin-top: -70px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.second .top {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  position: relative;
}

.second .bottom {
clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 14% 41%, 28% 51%, 49% 54%, 66% 53%, 79% 48%, 89% 39%, 100% 27%, 100% 100%, 47% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin-top: -70px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a useful link to generate path :

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

---

Here is another idea using `radial-gradient`

```css
.first  {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(100% 100% at top, #0000 60%, yellow 61%), 
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  
</div>
```

Using `mask` if you want transparency:

```css
.first  {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(100% 100% at top, #fff 60%, #0000 61%);
          mask:radial-gradient(100% 100% at top, #fff 60%, #0000 61%);
}
.bottom {
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(100% 100% at top, #0000 60%, #fff 61%);
          mask:radial-gradient(100% 100% at top, #0000 60%, #fff 61%);

}
body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  
</div>

<div class="first bottom">
  
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to make it more like on the picture which i provided because when I increase the width and height the curved part by itself starts to get some borders ?

Comment: @Mi yes you need in this case to change the path ;) use the link i provided, in this link you are able to specify the height/width of the picture then generate the path ... it's a bit tricky to do it by yourself. Or you may read more about clip path to understand how the values works so you can modify it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overlay top and bottom, just use clip path both ways (on the top or bottom element).`

```css
.transparent_bg {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 485px;  
    background: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.transparent_bg:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 485px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.transparent_bg {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 485px;  
    background: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.transparent_bg:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 485px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent_bg"></div>
```

Comment: is there any way to revert the color ? I mean top side of the oval to be transparent and the bottom side red for example ?

Comment: no sure why this answer got upvote ? i don't see what did you add to the initial code.