# CSS Curve over background image

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have been given this design by my designer and I have no idea how the best way to tackle the curves both above and below the image.

[image: Design with Curve]

I've considered clip-path but cannot figure out how to curve it. I don't want to use images if I can help it.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091451/curve-bottom-side-of-the-div-to-the-inside-with-css/48091526#48091526

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471393/how-to-create-a-curve-as-shown-below-for-the-div/47471484#47471484

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671820/curved-div-with-transparent-top/47672473#47672473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using border-radius.

```css
.box {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius:0% 0% 135% 135% / 0% 0% 255% 255%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```